# Model State in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use '/gazebo/Model_states' topic to get the model states.

shouldn't the include be like

```
#include gazebo_msgs/ModelStates.h
```

and  callback function be like

```
void ModelStatecallback(const gazebo_msgs::ModelStates::ConstPtr& msg)
{
}
```

Is anything wrong in this ?  When I tried this I get following error.

```
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h:121: error: ‘__s_getMD5Sum’ is not a member of ‘int’

/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h:138: error: ‘__s_getDataType’ is not a member of ‘int'
```

Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11749/model-state-in-gazebo/) by [adesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/737/adesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2011-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have had it [working](http://ibotics.ucsd.edu/trac/stingray/browser/trunk/stingray_model) for my robot by using

```
#include <gazebo/ModelState.h>
```

I think there is also an extra '_msgs' and 's' in your function, so try it as

```
void ModelStatecallback(const gazebo::ModelState::ConstPtr& msg)
{
}
```

Check out the [ROS Gazebo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gazebo) and [ModelState definition](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/gazebo/html/msg/ModelState.html) pages for more details.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2011-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/737/adesh/) on 2011-11-01**:
Hi Thomas, I already tried that combination as well but it does not work either.The 'ModelState definition' link that you posted  says 'This message is deprecated.Please use the version in gazebo_msgs instead' so I tried 'gazebo_msgs' and I want to know the position of a model so 'ModelStates'.